# Discrete maths Prove the argument is Valid or Invalid by inference

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

If my plumbing plans do not meet the construction code, then I cannot build my house.

If I hire a licensed contractor, then my plumbing plans will not meet the construction code.

I hire a licensed contractor.
Therefore I can build my house.

Prove by rule of inference is the argument valid or invalid :

**below is my attempt**

Premise 1: $\neg P \rightarrow \neg Q$  
Premise 2: $R \rightarrow \neg P$ 
Premise 3: $R$ 
Conclusion: $Q$

and to further prove the validity i used this method :

Premise 4 : $P \rightarrow Q$   (Inverse of premise 1)
Premise 5 : $\neg P$ (Modus ponens of premise 2 + 3) 
Premise 6 : $\ P$ (negation of premise 5)
$\ Q$ (Modus ponens of premise 4 and premise 6)

Comment: Premise 4 doesn't follow from Premise 1. Inverse are not logically equivalent. Hint: Instead, of inverse, take the contrapositive , q implies p. Use rules of inference to show that not Q is true. Conclude that the original argument is invalid. Alternatively, assume Q is true, then not Q is false. Can you derive a contradiction?

Comment: Thank you do much , i just realised they were not logically equivalent !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome! it's a good attempt, you almost have it.

Consider,

Premise 1: $\neg P \rightarrow \neg Q$  
Premise 2: $R \rightarrow \neg P$ 
Premise 3: $R$

By premise (2) and (3) + Modus Ponens we have: $ \neg P$

So,

premise 4:  $ \neg P$

by premise (1) and (4) + Modus Ponens

Conclusion: $\neg Q$

What can you say, about the truth of Q, given the above argument?

Comment: thank you so much for the guidance! I have figured out by myself the final solution to the problem